# How to access object joined with SQL using Room on Android

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I want to ask you for advice, how can I access object after using `LEFT JOIN` on two tables. I've got tables defined in external file File.db and I'm loading it to Room database on Android. I've got two tables defined:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`description`   TEXT,
`source_url`    TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Example_dates (
`id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`example_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
`color` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`date_from` TEXT,
`date_to`   TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(`example_id`) REFERENCES `Example`(`id`)
);
```

My entities are:

```
@Entity(
  tableName = "Example"
)
data class Example constructor(
  @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String?,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "source_url") var sourceUrl: String?
)

@Entity(
  tableName = "Example_dates",
  foreignKeys = arrayOf(
    ForeignKey(entity = Example::class, parentColumns = ["id"], 
     childColumns = ["example_id"]))
)
data class Example_dates constructor(
  @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "example_id") var exampleId: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "color") var color: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "date_from") var dateFrom: String?,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "date_to") var dateTo: String?
)
```

Dao object:

```
@Dao
interface AnimalDao {
  @Query(
    "SELECT * FROM example_dates LEFT JOIN example ON example_dates.example_id = example.id")
  fun loadAll(): Cursor
}
```

And I'm building DB like this:

```
RoomAsset
  .databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "File.db")
  .build()
```

Is there any way, how to get merged data from SQL statement in different way then Cursor? I've tried to add more fields to `data class Example` constructor annotated with `@Ignore` but I got error with differences in table - "Expected/Found". Or is solution based on cursor the right way of implementation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as official documentation said https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data

> "It's highly discouraged to work with the Cursor API because it doesn't guarantee whether the rows exist or what values the rows contain."

so I tried to create another `data class named ExampleDetail` with all fields I need and in `DAO` object I'm returning List instead of Cursor.

Thank you.